# Why is the base 64 encoding not working?

Tags: swift, base64

I am trying to post username and password to a php script, it works fine when it is not encoded, but I am having trouble encoding on the ios end. When I print crypt I get `<64584e6c 636d3568 6257566b 59585268 50556377 4e444134 4d546335 4a6e4268 63334e33 62334a6b 5a474630 59543172 6448526e 4e6a5935 4d673d3d>`, but based on the tutorials I should be getting a string along the lines of `bXkgcGxhbmkgdGV4dA==`

```
var bodyData = "usernamedata=\(self.username.text!)&passworddata=\(self.password.text!)"


    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let encodeString = (bodyData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!);
    let crypt = encodeString.base64EncodedDataWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
    request.HTTPBody = crypt
    print(crypt)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I wouldn't recommend using `encodeString` as a variable name for something whose type is NSData (not a String).
2. The function `base64EncodedDataWithOptions` returns NSData. If you want a string like `bXkgcGxhbmkgdGV4dA==`, you can use `base64EncodedStringWithOptions`.

Comment: Looks like request.HTTPBody only accepts NSData, but php accepts a string.

Comment: If you read the documentation, you will find that `base64EncodedDataWithOptions` returns the same string, encoded as UTF-8. It's correct that HTTPBody is treated as NSData (usually UTF-8) while the URL is built from a string.

Comment: So my original code is indeed correct? Because when I decode the username and password in the php script I don't get any values back. I'm assuming because `base64_decode` decodes strings.

Comment: Right, but PHP probably returns the body as a string already. Without showing your PHP code it's hard to guess what's wrong. You might also want to use NSURLComponents/NSURLQueryItem to build the body string, or at least be sure to manually escape any `&`/`=` that might be in the username/password.

Comment: I know that the php code is correct, but is there some type of method in php to decrypt NSData? Cause like before when I run the base64_decide method and print the result I get a nil

Answer (score 0):

You should have to write it like,

```
let crypt = encodeString.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
```

Comment: Looks like request.HTTPBody only accepts NSData, but php accepts a string.